# How to assign swarm manager nodes properly?

Tags: azure, docker, amazon-ec2, openstack, docker-swarm

At least three manager nodes are required in production on docker swarm mode.
I think that those nodes have to be deployed on different physical machines.
How to guarantee that on cloud service such as AWS, Azure?

Answer (score 0):

In cloud environments, you would deploy your managers to separate availability zones to avoid single points of failure impacting multiple managers simultaneously. This includes a physical node outage as well as a power, networking, or other data center wide outage.